# How to display name instead of id on Yii2 without relationship

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have two tables one is user another one is comment but I am not using any kind of foreign keys. I want to display name instead of id from user table on detail view. How can I do that? My detail view code is as follows:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
          'model' => $model,
          //To hide labels
          //'model' => $model,
          'template' => '<tr><td{contentOptions}>{value}</td></tr>',
          'attributes' => [
               [
                 'attribute' => 'user_id',
                 'format' => 'raw',
                 'label' =>'',
                 'value'=>Html::a($model->user_id, Url::toRoute(['/profile-user/view?id='.$model->user_id.''])),
               ],
          ],
      ]) ?>
```

The expected out put is like this

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
          'model' => $model,
          //To hide labels
          //'model' => $model,
          'template' => '<tr><td{contentOptions}>{value}</td></tr>',
          'attributes' => [
               [
                 'attribute' => 'user_id',
                 'format' => 'raw',
                 'label' =>'',
                 'value'=>Html::a($model->username, Url::toRoute(['/profile-user/view?id='.$model->user_id.''])),
               ],
          ],
      ]) ?>
```

Comment: seems you have the same code  in the expected  output  .. try explain better ..

Comment: I just want $model-userame on the output thats it The problem is i havnt defined any forighn key thats the problem

Comment: $model  is related  at  comment table?

Comment: No relationship is defined Aka no foreign key.

Comment: the username you are looking for is the name of the logged  user_id?

Comment: No,Thats from another  table called comment

Comment: Somthing like SELECT username from comment where user_id = comment.user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `username` is the name of the user logged then you could use `Yii::$app->user->identity->username`:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
      'model' => $model,
      //To hide labels
      //'model' => $model,
      'template' => '<tr><td{contentOptions}>{value}</td></tr>',
      'attributes' => [
           [
             'attribute' => 'user_id',
             'format' => 'raw',
             'label' => '',
             'value' => Html::a(
                 Yii::$app->user->identity->username,
                 Url::toRoute(['/profile-user/view', 'id' => $model->user_id])
             ),
           ],
      ],
  ]) ?>
```

If the `username` is a column of a `User` model with id as primary key you could use:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
      'model' => $model,
      //To hide labels
      //'model' => $model,
      'template' => '<tr><td{contentOptions}>{value}</td></tr>',
      'attributes' => [
           [
             'attribute' => 'user_id',
             'format' => 'raw',
             'label' => '',
             'value' => Html::a(
                 User::findOne($model->user_id)->username,
                 Url::toRoute(['/profile-user/view', 'id' => $model->user_id])
             ),
           ],
      ],
  ]) ?>
```

Comment: i have update  the answer  using  $model->user_id instead  $user_id